# GeoCoordinates schema not picked by Google for Pickup/Dropoff location in Car Rentals schema

Tags: google-schemas

[GeoCoordinates](https://schema.org/GeoCoordinates) schema is not picked by Google for Pickup/Dropoff location in [Car Rentals schema](https://schema.org/RentalCarReservation)

In Email Markup Tester, The error

> 'Property Geo is invalid for this type of object'

is shown

In The below code piece, the pickupLocation schema is used from the CarRental Schema. Using GeoCoordinates schema within these is throwing an error. 
Code:

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
    <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="26%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding: 0 0 0 0; font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #999999; font-weight: 600; font-size: 12px; line-height: 22px; text-align: left;" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="flex-p-bold">
                Pickup Address:
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="70%" align="right" class="responsive-table">
        <tr itemprop="pickupLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
            <td align="center" style="padding: 0 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #999999; font-weight: 400; font-size: 12px; text-align: left;" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="flex-p">
                <span class="appleBody" style="color:#999999;">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="Linkshelf - Pickup Location">
                <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                <span itemprop="streetAddress">12345 Main Street <br />
                <span itemprop="addressLocality">Koramangala <br />
                <span itemprop="addressRegion">Bengaluru <br />
                <span itemprop="postalCode">560034 <br />
                <span itemprop="telephone">12345678 <br />
                <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content = "India">
                <span itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
                    <meta itemprop="latitude" content="40.75" />
                    <meta itemprop="longitude" content="73.98" />
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>           
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you be able to post your code to help identify the specific problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have marked your error message with a >.  Please post your code here so that users can help you.

Comment: It could be possible it's just that there's a bug with the Markup Tester (https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester), since the documentation states dropoffLocation and pickupLocation properties both accept the value Place which accepts geo (https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/types/Place). I'd like to add that the address fields are required for the of the car rentals schema, so I believe Maps will go off the address you input.